# What is the norm for positioning models in model space?

Tags: opengl, graphics, matrix, directx

Are most models centered at the origin, or is there bottom at the origin, or something else?

I ask because in my app I have to store world positions of objects, and I'm not sure if the position should designate their center, the bottom center, or something else. I would like it to match with how it's done in model space so it makes transformations easier.

What is the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard for this but centering model at origin is a convenient way to do things; it is easier to define bounding volumes this way for primitives you often have simpler formulas defining them.

Unless there is some problem with models you have I'd set position of model space origin as world space position this is easiest way to go and works ok in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Model space is so named because it is the space in which the model resides. The choice is completely arbitrary, and is usually defined either by convention (for a particular team) or by whatever the artist who created the model wants.

So if you have control of your models, then you should use whatever space makes it most convenient for you to build your models or by whatever the consuming code expects them to be. It's all up to you.

Comment: I understand that, I just would like to know of a convention or what most people use. Do you think what Vasaka said is the convention?

Comment: @BlazArt: My point is that there is no "the convention". It's completely arbitrary. Everyone has their own model space.